# Please undelete my question as it is helping many leaners

Tags: discussion, status-declined, specific-question

Please undelete my question as it is helping many leaners . 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034265/apple-swift-programming-language-pdf-ebook-provided-by-apple-on-ibook

Comment: Stack Overflow is not Google

Comment: **Please stop** leaving comments on unrelated posts about the deletion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22046530/how-can-i-make-the-play-game-services-not-automatically-sign-in-at-the-startup#comment42428784_22046530 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892334/get-size-of-all-tables-in-database/7892349#comment41996307_7892349. All of your most recent comments are the same; this is not the right use of comments.

Answer (score 43):

I'm sorry, but that's not even a question. It's just a title and a link to Apple's Swift ebook, which anyone could find by searching in iBooks or elsewhere.

Stack Overflow is a place for questions and answers, not a link repository for offsite resources. I see little reason to undelete this, as this information can be found more readily elsewhere.

Comment: But it helped many leaners

Comment: @KaranDua Not really, no. A simple Google search for "swift pdf" yields the exact PDF document you linked as result #2. Stack Overflow does not need to host a link to another place. **That is the worst kind of content we can have.** All you're doing is bringing people here when they don't need to come here. They could just click the *correct* link straight from Google.